# How to use model field in it's serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to have my own error messages, which I've implemented in serializer like this:

```
class TransactionsValuesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Translations
        fields = ('id', 'value')
        extra_kwargs = {"value": {"error_messages": {"blank": f"Error"}}}
```

It's model

```
class Translations(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'merchants__translations'

    value = models.TextField()
    key = models.ForeignKey(
        TranslationsKeys,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='translations'
    )
    translation_language = models.ForeignKey(
        TranslationLanguages,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='translations'
    )
```

Now, if user do not enter some of the fields for translations, it will show error message 'Error'.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc3ab.png)

Is there a way to output error message like 'Error in {key}'?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın I want to get model field and put it's value to the error message. Model contains field 'key'. I want to get it and place to the error to display in which field we get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never saw that usage of extra_kwargs for this. Maybe you should go like this.
Serializers already raise an error for required fields when they're empty. It shows the field name automatically.
The default behaviour is already required=True for serializer fields.

So, I think your serializer is good for now. Then, when you make a request without including value field, serializer should raise something like this.

HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST
{'value': ['This field may not be blank.']}

I think you already have the key name `value` which is what you want.

Comment: I need an error like '{field} cannot be empty'.

Comment: If there are several empty fields, serializer raises "This field may not be blank" several times. I want to give a user some more exact instructions.

Comment: Well, it already returns error messages for each field. Maybe you can process that error message on frontend and then show error messages for each field. This is how it's done in Django admin. It returns errors for each field separately and then django displays it for each field.
I think what you want can be easily done on frontend. You can do it in backend using a custom validators but it might result ugly code at the end.